# how to draw a line using pureimage?

Tags: node.js, png, drawing

I'm new to node.js and this is just a small thing I need as part of a project that I'm writing in a different language.

How would I go about using pureimage to make a line from a start position to an end position and exporting it as a png?
I'm interested in using pureimage because to my understanding you can set the line width with a variable

I currently have a working program with pngjs-draw but it's impossible to change line width there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the line thickness with the [lineWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth) property. Then you can draw your line in the canvas 2D context and export your image as a png file with *pureimage*, like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PImage = require('pureimage');

let img = PImage.make(100, 50);
let ctx = img.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 5;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 50);
ctx.stroke(); 

PImage.encodePNGToStream(img, fs.createWriteStream('out.png'));
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.
But how would I wait for it to finish writing the file before I do something with that file?

Comment: Note that this method is not related to pureimage but _canvas_.